# Adding translation to a custom module

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I cannot make the module translation strings to be considered, unistalling and installing the module again.

Is the indicated .po relative path correct?

in my module blockForm function i have :

```
  $form['retrieval_method'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => $this->t('Retrieval Method'),
  );
```

my .info.yml

```
name: 'amu hal'
type: module
description: display publications from HAL
core: 8.x
version: 8.x-3.0
package: AMU
project: 'amu_hal'
interface translation project: amu_hal
interface translation server pattern: modules/amu_hal/translations/%language.po
```

and in

> /sites/mysite/modules/amu_hal/translations/fr.po :

```
msgid "Retrieval Method"

msgstr "Méthode d'extraction"
```

i have activated the core interface traduction module and the

> /fr/admin/reports/translations

tells me Missing translations for 11 projects:

> ```
> amu hal (8.x-3.0). File not found at modules/amu_hal/translations/fr.po
> ```

Comment: wrap the keys in single quotes

Comment: which keys ? this: interface translation project: 'amu_hal'. Does not change

Comment: The keys are on the left, so `'interface translation project': amu_hal`, for example

Comment: which ones then ? because if i wrap them all, the module is not listed in the extend interface

Comment: Does it help to read the documentation - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.5.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to comments and doc , i have moved the whole module in modules/custom/ and for info file:

```
name: 'amu hal'
type: module
description: display publications from HAL
core: 8.x
version: 8.x-3.0
package: AMU
project: amu_hal
'interface translation project': amu_hal
'interface translation server pattern': modules/custom/amu_hal/translations/amu_hal-%language.po
```

Placing the po file at

> modules/custom/mymodule/translations/mymodule-fr.po

now i could update the translation at

> /fr/admin/reports/translations

and make string translations

Note that the same po file is not found if the module is placed in sites/mysite/module

Comment: `public://` means file upload directory, usually `.../sites/default/files/...`, I've successfully used a relative path from web root in my own module: `modules/custom/MY_MODULE/translations/MY_MODULE-%version-%language.po`

Comment: The `'` seems to be very important for the key on the right side: `'interface translation server pattern':` (correct) vs `interface translation server pattern:` (not correct)

Comment: Following works: interface translation server pattern: modules/custom/module/translations/module.%language.po, just remember to clear cache after changing info file